# Spilled failed in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop

While running Map Reduce program including mapper,combiner and reducer the terminal is showing the Spilled failed error but when i am running the program with mapper alone it is not given any spilled.

15/09/02 13:56:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: TaskIdattempt_201508260430_0030_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Spill failed at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1007)atorg.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:689)at

Answer (score 1):

When you are running a job with reducer, the intermediate data of map output would be put under a process before spilling it into a local disk. There is a background process/thread which sorts your data and writes the data to different partitions depending on the number of reducers. The problem with your job is that, the tasktracker which is running the map task doesn't have enough local memory space to save your intermediate data. But when you run a map only job the sort and shuffle doesn't take place, it directly writes your output to HDFS. Try compressing your intermediate map output and set your compression codec depending on your file size. I usually prefer snappy.

```
<property>
  <name> mapreduce.map.output.compress</name> 
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
```

Comment: after changing the <name> mapreduce.map.output.compress</name> 
                             <value>true</value> when i am re running the jar it is still showing value as false.

Comment: I got it we have to execute the command after making the changes in the mapred-site.xml file. The command will re configure the changes made in the xml file.  cmd is syncconf.sh hadoop

Comment: Then maybe you have to increase the slave node memory size